# Unwanted offset appears on left and top of the browser

Tags: html

Even when I'm using this simple code, the browser shows a little offset on left and top. How to fix this. Code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style="text/css">
#container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If my answer (which you accepted) helped you, would you up-vote it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because most browsers use a standard CSS stylesheet (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).

One of the rules sets the `margin` of the `body` to 8 pixels:

```
body {
    margin: 8px;
}
```

You can disable it by setting the `margin` to 0 pixels:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4yJP/1/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: However, this resets the `margin` and `padding` on *every* element. That's a bit excessive in my opinion.

Comment: @toothbrush Actually, you just need to add `margin` or `padding` for an element when neccessary. Above style is just one of the basic technique to `reset` css to make it compatible along browsers. For complete technique, you can refer to some css scripts on [cssreset.com](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Comment: OK. I was just thinking that resetting it on **every** element was a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me all the time:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

even better:

```
*{
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `margin-top` and `margin-left` of `html` and `body` 0.

```
html, body{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left:0;
}
```